# Passing a custom Object from one Activity to another Parcelable vs Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to pass a custom Object from one activity to another, the Object consists of a String and a List of another custom Object which consists of an array of strings and an array of ints. I've read  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/830104, but then I've found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842273/830104. Which is better to use Bundle or Parcelable? What is the difference? When should I use this each? 
Thanks for your replies, 
Dan

Comment: If your object consists only strings, array of strings and array of ints then just make the class serializable and use the `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` method of `Intent` when startung the next `Activity`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Parcelable` and `Bundle` are not exclusive concepts; you can even deploy both on your app at a time.

[1] Term `Parcelable` comes with Serialization concept in Java (and other high-level language such as C#, Python,...). It ensures that an object - which remains in RAM store - of such `Parcelable` class can be **saved** in file stream such as text or memory (offline status) then can be reconstructed to be used in program at runtime (online status).

**In an Android application**, within 2 `independent activities` (exclusively running - one starts then other will have to stop):

There will be NO pointer from current activity to refer to previous one and its members - because previous activity is stopped and cleared out form memory; so that to **maintain object's value passed to next activity** (called from `Intent`) the object need to be `parcelable` (`serializable`).

[2] While **`Bundle`** is normally the Android concept, denotes that a variable or group of variables. If look into lower level, it can be considered as HashMap with key-value pairs.

**Conclusion:**

- **`Bundle`** is to store many objects with related keys, it can save any object in native types, but it **doesn't know** how to save a **complex object** (which contains an ArrayList for example)
- **`Parcelable`** class is to ensure a complex instance of it can be **`serialized`** and **`de-serialized`** during runtime. This object can contains complex types such as ArrayList, HashMap, array, or struct,...

**[UPDATED] - Example:**

```
//Class without implementing Parcelable will cause error 
//if passing though activities via Intent
public class NoneParcelable
{
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public NoneParcelable()
    {
        nameList.add("abc");
        nameList.add("xyz");            
    }
}

//Parcelable Class's objects can be exchanged 
public class GoodParcelable implements Parcelable
{
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public GoodParcelable()
    {
        nameList.add("Can");
        nameList.add("be parsed");          
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        // Serialize ArrayList name here            
    }
}
```

**In source activity:**

```
NoneParcelable nonePcl = new NoneParcelable();
GoodParcelable goodPcl = new GoodParcelable();
int count = 100;

Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("NONE_P",nonePcl);
i.putExtra("GOOD_P",goodPcl);
i.putExtra("COUNT", count);
```

**In destination activity:**

```
Intent i = getIntent();

//this is BAD:
NoneParcelable nP = (NoneParcelable)i.getExtra("NONE_P"); //BAD code

//these are OK:
int count = (int)i.getExtra("COUNT");//OK
GoodParcelable myParcelableObject=(GoodParcelable)i.getParcelableExtra("GOOD_P");// OK
```

Comment: Actually, Bundle is a concrete implementation of Parcelable. You avoid the scary Parcelable interface by simply creating a Bundle object from the data of your object and using intent.putExtra("myObj", myObj.toBundle()) / MyObjecet.fromBundle(intent.getBundleExtra("myObj")) to store/retrieve it. You have to implement toBundle()/fromBundle() yourself, similar to storing your object properties into a hashmap.